# EF6: PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.HasColumnName vs. DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

If the name of a field in a table of my database differs from the name of the property in my domain class, there are, to the best of my knowledge, two different ways to solve that:
Let's imagine, we have table `Author` with a field `FIRST_NAME` and in the code we have an entity `Author` with a property `FirstName`, then:
1.Using `PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.HasColumnName`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().Property(e => e.FirstName).HasColumnName("FIRST_NAME");
```

2.Use Annotations:

```
[Column("FIRST_NAME")] 
public String FirstName { get; set; }
```

My question is if there is difference between these two options and when to prefer one of them over the other one?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the annotations as it's the simplest for maintenance and human reference; this is with the caveat that you have access to the class you're using for the entity.

I consider the model builder to be similar to extensions where it allows you to leverage classes that you can access from references and packages.

So in your example, if `Author` is a class in your solution, I'd use annotations. But if the same class was from a Nuget package then I'd have no option but to use the model builder.